# Decompile Weight Loss App

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Where can the gifs in these applications be stored? [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menloseweight.loseweightappformen.weightlossformen)

1. I decompiled the APK but found no results
2. I looked in the data folder with the help of a rooted device but couldn't find anything.
3. I noticed that there is still data in my app when I login without internet which means it is not downloading over internet

There is only one question; Where might these files be stored?

Comment: You should examine the APK file more carefully then you would notice the folder "lottie". The decompiled code shows that it contains the library [airbnb lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/) which renders Adobe After Effects animations. Most likely these files are those form the lottie folder.

Comment: drawable or mipmap?

Comment: @Robert yes i noticed it but json file is corrupt

Comment: Your question is not very specific, because the res/drawable* folders contains a lot of  images like buttons in PNG format. But I assume you are not talking about those images.

Comment: @Robert No, I'm talking about them, I'm commenting. I'm talking about animations that do sports within the application.

Answer (score -1):

In the 'Res' directory after decompiling

Comment: I couldnt find it